# Chat is down. Where can I find when it'll be back up?

Tags: support, chat, stackstatus

Chat is down network-wide. Where can I find when it'll be back up?

Comment: Ask a dev, on chat. Oh wait...

Comment: Well, MSE chat is working.

Comment: Chat is working for me, what exactly do you see?

Comment: Chat has been back online for almost 24 hours now...

Comment: Just a regular timeout. Back up not. Voted to close as no longer reproducible.

Comment: It's down again.

Comment: I concur. It's down for Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. Edit: Now it's back.

Answer (score -2):

You can find these things on the official Twitter account of Stack Exchange:

http://twitter.com/StackStatus

Comment: The chat is down again, and there hasn't been information on the Twitter account.